# load text file with a specific format to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load my `.txt` file into a pandas `csv` file:

```
file(.txt)

uid: hdadmin01
displayName: Help Desk Engineering
ttgAuthEnv:

uid: audit01
displayName: AUDIT & Security
ttgAuthEnv:


uid: operator
displayName: Operator F.M.
ttgCreationDate: 18/11/2008
ttgAuthEnv: csttst
```

i need to convert the txt file in csv file with 4 columns `('uid', 'displayname', 'ttgCreationDate', 'ttgAuthEnv')`

```
Column1        Column2                 Column3        Column4
uid         displayName            ttgCreationDate   tgAuthEnv
hdadmin01    Help Desk Engineering      
audit01      AUDIT & Security       
operator     Operator F.M.           18/11/2008         csttst
```

can anyone help me to solve this, it is a bit complicated?
thanks in advance.

i am using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv 

data = pd.read_csv('file.txt')
data.columns = ["uid", "displayName", "ttgCreationDate", "ttgAuthEnv"]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your own attempts, including thoughts or initial code snippets. Also, please see how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i am not able to attach the pandas format that i need.